# Failed to start thread despite using Executors.fixedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading

I have code that is supposed to do as requests as fast as possible. `dataFetcher` internally uses `client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();` which calls my server on the localhost. JDK documentation states that it's a blocking call.

```
private static void callServer(DataFetcher dataFetcher, int times) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            executorService.submit(dataFetcher::fetch);
        }
}
```

when I set argument `times` to a big enough number like 5000, I'm getting several errors like this:

`[3.882s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.`

My question is how is that possible to get such an error, given we use fixed thread pool. Why would JRE try to spin a new thread? I have also counted the fulfilled request on my server (using AtomicInteger) and it looks like only part of desired connections are being made.

This is the documentation for the .newFixedThreadPool() method:

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads
> operating off a shared unbounded queue.  At any point, at most
> {@code nThreads} threads will be active processing tasks.
> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active,
> they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

Comment: could not reproduce. Create a reproduceable test.

Answer (score 0):

one problem with the above code is that `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);` is inside the function. Hence a new pool is initialised every time, leaving many un-cleared threads.

The FixedThreadPool service must be initialised outside the function call and only ONCE. Also 5K threads is large, if you need that many ensure proper Memory sizing.

Comment: I invoke `callServer()` only once, in the `main()` method of my program. The only repeting part is inside the for loop.